# Copy Text out of VirtualBox VM?

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, user-interface

I have a Windows XP VM running in VirtualBox, and I am unable to copy text into my clipboard on the host machine. I can, however, copy text into the VM. Is there some setting I am missing?

Comment: Do you have Guest Additions installed?

Comment: I do now. Thats the answer.

Comment: @Zoot You should post your comment as an answer so it can be flagged as the answer to the problem.

Comment: @Matt Jenkins Gotcha.  Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest installing Guest Additions for your virtual machine.
Instructions for doing so can be found [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html).